# Name for a module with only one associated prime

Tags: translation, ac.commutative-algebra, ag.algebraic-geometry

In EGA IV<sub>2</sub>, Def. 3.2.4, Grothendieck defines a quasicoherent sheaf over a locally Noetherian scheme to be "*irredondant*" if it has a unique associated point. Presumeably, a module over a Noetherian ring is *irredondant* if it has a unique associated prime. However, googling gives no relevant results for "irredundant sheaf" or "irredundant module" (which I can understand, since it is rather a peculiar name).

How is this term usually rendered into English? Ideally, answers should include at least one reference to a text or paper using this term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lasker-Noether_theorem) calls a module over a commutative
Noetherian ring with only
one associated prime a *coprimary* module. I don't recall hearing
this terminology elsewhere, but it is certainly common to call
a submodule $N$ of $M$ a *primary* submodule if $M/N$ is coprimary.

Comment: Googling this gives enough relevant hits to make me think that it's probably the standard term (if there is one).

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's what Eisenbud uses as well.